# JRequest Method in Joomla 4

Tags: php, javascript, joomla-4.x, joomla-4, html

JRequest Remove from Joomla 4 then how i must use this method

for example

```
    $controller->execute( JRequest::getCmd('task', $view)
```

not work
i must change it to what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some of the current code inside my controller:

```
function add() {
    if(JRequest::checkToken( 'get' )) {
        JRequest::checkToken( 'get' ) or die( 'Invalid Token' );
    } else {
        JRequest::checkToken() or die( 'Invalid Token' );
    }
    JRequest::setVar('hidemainmenu', 1);        
    $model = $this->getModel('albums');
    
    $view = $this->getView('albums', 'html');               
    $view->setModel($model, true);      
    $view->setLayout('add');
    $view->add();
}
```

It must be changed to:

```
function add() {
    if(Factory::getApplication()->getInput()->get('get')) {
        Factory::getApplication()->getInput()->get('get') or die( 'Invalid Token' );
    } else {
        JFactory::getApplication()->getInput() or die( 'Invalid Token' );
    }
    
    $this->input->get('hidemainmenu', 1);   
    $model = $this->getModel('albums');
    
    $view = $this->getView('albums', 'html');               
    $view->setModel($model, true);      
    $view->setLayout('add');
    $view->add();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Joomla\Input\Input` class. Instance relevant to the current request can be accessed through the application:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$controller->execute(Factory::getApplication()->getInput()->get('task', $view));
```

Inside controllers you should already have the input instance injected which you could use like this:

```
$this->input->get('inputVar');
```

Comment: can you check my code and if this is true tell me ?