# JRequest Error to Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, jrequest

I use this code on my component in Joomla 3:

```
function add() {
    if(JRequest::checkToken( 'get' )) {
        JRequest::checkToken( 'get' ) or die( 'Invalid Token' );
    } else {
        JRequest::checkToken() or die( 'Invalid Token' );
    }
    
    JRequest::setVar('hidemainmenu', 1);        
    $model = $this->getModel('albums');
    
    $view = $this->getView('albums', 'html');               
    $view->setModel($model, true);      
    $view->setLayout('add');
    $view->add();
}
```

but I receive `JRequest Error` in Joomla 4.

Comment: Did you see these on the Joomla Forum? [How do i replace deprecated JRequest](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=808&t=989473), [JRequest replacement in Joomla 4](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=989199)  Was Sharky's advice to you here on JSE not helpful? [JRequest Method in Joomla 4](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/32148/12352)  Did you forget that [you posted this answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/32154/12352)?

Comment: @mickmackusa i receive again this error i think my method is wrong this method i use not work and i dont know how use this new method i ask question like this and if i receive answer i delete other question because this question is better than before and many people problem fix with this

Answer (score -1):

Use this for JRequest error

```
<?php if( Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()->getInput()->get('view') != 'article' ): ?>
```

Inside a module you can simplify it to this:

```
<?php if( $app->getInput()->get('view') != 'article' ): ?>
```